# lib for Nonlinear Fitting on iOS

Tags: ios, open-source, statistics

I need to fit some data in an iOS app, basically with Newton's Law of Cooling:

```
y = a + b * c^{x}
```

I found the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Initializing-the-Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Solver.html) is likely to handle this, however, it is out of consideration for the sake of GPL. Is there any open-sourced nonlinear Chi-Square solver in C/C++ with a commercial friendly license (e.g., BSD, APL etc.)?

Looking forward to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MINPACK could do the job.

https://github.com/johannesgerer/jburkardt-cpp/tree/master/minpack