# Generalized Reduced Gradient algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, nonlinear-optimization

I am working on some science project and I need the C language implementation of Generalized Reduced Gradient algorithm for non-linear optimization. Is there any library or just a piece of code for that? Or, please suggest any other solution for non-linear multivariable problems. I am looking to build an optimization model using 4 independent variables and 2 constants: the model is nonlinear.
I have checked with Microsoft Excel's Solver using generalized reduced gradient (GRG) is solving this model perfectly, but I need this in the C language for my simulations.

Here is my excel solution:
http://speedy.sh/SEdZj/eof-cs-rest.xlsm
I have used Microsoft Excel Solver with GRG algorithm to search for a minimum value of SS and the output are values of Const_a and Const_b.

Comment: Mathlab or Wolferam?  First things that pop into my mind for this sort of thing.  Also ask it at Math Overflow here.

Comment: Is this a non-linear model based on a system of ordinary differential equations? What is the differnece between a "constant" and an "independent variable" here?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I have tried solver in Excel and it is working fine. Now i need to implement something like that in C.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Matlab, Mathematica and Excel are great for this kind of a problem, but i need to implement a solution in C language.

Comment: @s.bandara it is something like f(x1,x2,x3,x4)=y, where i have vectors with values of y,x1,x2,x3,x4. y=A*exp(-x1*(x2*B^2 + x3*B +x4)). Now y is dependent variable and x1,x2,x3,x4 are independent variables, A and B are constants which i am looking for. So algorithm should find such a A and B to fit vectors i provide.

Comment: If you can put together a formula or post in your original question your excel solution, we can make a C solution pretty quickly from that...

Comment: One general comment for whatever your solution will be: log-transform.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I have added a file with excel solution, please have look, and thank you in advance

Comment: Bah - not at a place where I can safely download stuff - at work and all.  Here's hoping someone else can get to that sooner than I.  Sorry!

Comment: @darko_5 did you find the C code in for GRG2 in the end?

Comment: @darko_5 in fact I meant LSGRG2 in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONOPT as distributed by [GAMS](http://www.gams.com/mccarl/mccarlhtml/index.html?conopt.htm) seems an established implementation of GRG, but is not free (although demo may be sufficient for you).

Alglib has an implementation of non-linear Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm [here](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/levenbergmarquardt.php) and is GPL / commercial licensed.

Sample code using alglib below:

```
/*
 * Simple optimiser example
 *
 * nl_opt.cpp
 *
 * Compile with eg 'g++ -I../tools/alglib/src ../tools/alglib/src/ap.cpp ../tools/alglib/src/alglibinternal.cpp ../tools/alglib/src/linalg.cpp ../tools/alglib/src/alglibmisc.cpp ../tools/alglib/src/solvers.cpp ../tools/alglib/src/optimization.cpp nl_opt.cpp -o opt'
 *
 */

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "optimization.h"

using namespace std;

double fn(double a1, double a2, double a3, double x, double A, double B)
{
    return A * exp(-x*(a1*B*B+a2*B+a3));
}

struct problem
{
    double *m_a1s;
    double *m_a2s;
    double *m_a3s;
    double *m_xs;
    double *m_ys;

    int m_n;

    problem(double *a1s, double *a2s, double *a3s, double *xs, double *ys, int n) 
        : m_a1s(a1s), m_a2s(a2s), m_a3s(a3s), m_xs(xs), m_ys(ys), m_n(n)
    {
    }

    void fn_vec(const alglib::real_1d_array &c_var, alglib::real_1d_array &fi, void *ptr)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m_n; ++i)
        {
            double yhat = fn(m_a1s[i], m_a2s[i], m_a3s[i], m_xs[i], c_var[0], c_var[1]);
            double err_sq = (m_ys[i] - yhat) * (m_ys[i] - yhat);
            sum += err_sq;
        }
        fi[0] = sum;
    }
};

problem *g_p;

void fn_vec(const alglib::real_1d_array &c_var, alglib::real_1d_array &fi, void *ptr)
{
    g_p->fn_vec(c_var, fi, ptr);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Testing non-linear optimizer..." << endl;

    int n = 5;
    double a1s[] = {2.42, 4.78, 7.25, 9.55, 11.54};
    double a2s[] = {4.25, 5.27, 6.33, 7.32, 8.18};
    double a3s[] = {3.94, 4.05, 4.17, 4.28, 4.37};

    double xs[] = {0.024, 0.036, 0.048, 0.06, 0.072};
    double ys[] = {80, 70, 50, 40, 45};

    double initial[] = {150, 1.75};
    double ss_init = 0.0;

    cout << "Initial problem:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        double yhat = fn(a1s[i], a2s[i], a3s[i], xs[i], initial[0], initial[1]);
        double err_sq = (ys[i] - yhat) * (ys[i] - yhat);
        ss_init += err_sq;
        cout << a1s[i] << "\t" << a2s[i] << "\t" << a3s[i] << "\t" 
            << xs[i] << "\t" << ys[i] << "\t" << yhat << "\t" << err_sq << endl;
    }
    cout << "Error: " << ss_init << endl;

    // create problem
    problem p(a1s, a2s, a3s, xs, ys, n);
    g_p = &p;

    // setup solver
    alglib::real_1d_array x = "[150.0, 1.75]";
    double epsg = 0.00000001;
    double epsf = 0;
    double epsx = 0;

    alglib::ae_int_t maxits = 0;
    alglib::minlmstate state;
    alglib::minlmreport report;

    alglib::minlmcreatev(2, x, 0.0001, state);
    alglib::minlmsetcond(state, epsg, epsf, epsx, maxits);

    // optimize
    alglib::minlmoptimize(state, fn_vec);

    alglib::minlmresults(state, x, report);

    cout << "Results:" << endl;

    cout << report.terminationtype << endl;
    cout << x.tostring(2).c_str() << endl;

    double ss_end = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        double yhat = fn(a1s[i], a2s[i], a3s[i], xs[i], x[0], x[1]);
        double err_sq = (ys[i] - yhat) * (ys[i] - yhat);
        ss_end += err_sq;
        cout << a1s[i] << "\t" << a2s[i] << "\t" << a3s[i] << "\t"
             << xs[i] << "\t" << ys[i] << "\t" << yhat << "\t" << err_sq << endl;
    }
    cout << "Error: " << ss_end << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives sample output:

```
./opt 
Testing non-linear optimizer...
Initial problem:
2.42    4.25    3.94    0.024   80  95.5553 241.968
4.78    5.27    4.05    0.036   70  54.9174 227.485
7.25    6.33    4.17    0.048   50  24.8537 632.338
9.55    7.32    4.28    0.06    40  9.3038  942.257
11.54   8.18    4.37    0.072   45  3.06714 1758.36
Error: 3802.41
Results:
2
[92.22,0.57]
2.42    4.25    3.94    0.024   80  77.6579 5.48528
4.78    5.27    4.05    0.036   70  67.599  5.76475
7.25    6.33    4.17    0.048   50  56.6216 43.8456
9.55    7.32    4.28    0.06    40  46.0026 36.0314
11.54   8.18    4.37    0.072   45  36.6279 70.0922
Error: 161.219
```

Comment: also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854917/lib-for-nonlinear-fitting-on-ios points to this [MINPACK](https://github.com/johannesgerer/jburkardt-cpp/tree/master/minpack) implementation. Not sure what platform you are targetting?

Comment: i have actually used an Alglib, and have it compiled to use it with objective-c, because it is for os x platfrom

Comment: By the way i have used the interpolation.h part of the Alglib and i've read it is just a wrapper for optimization's curve fitting algorithms. Hope that was good call.